# Is it a good idea to iterate through several browsers in one test using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: loops, testing, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to run a simple test on multiple browsers, here is a mock up of the code I've got:

```
String url = "http://www.anyURL.com";
WebDriver[] drivers = { new FireFoxDriver(), new InternetExplorerDriver, 
                        newChromDriver() };

@Test
public void testTitle() {

     for (int i = 0; i < drivers.length; i++) {

         // navigate to the desired url 
         drivers[i].get(url);

         // assert that the page title starts with foo
         assertTrue(drivers[i].getTitle().startsWith("foo"));

         // close current browser session
         drivers[i].quit();

     }// end for

}// end test
```

For some reason this code is opening multiple browsers seemingly before the first iteration of loop is completed.
What is actually happening here? and what is a good/better way to do this?

Please understand that I am by no means a professional programmer, and I am also brand new to using Selenium, so if what I am attempting is generally bad practice please let me know, but please don't be rude about it. I will respect your opinion much more if you are respectful in your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not.

In fact, most of the test frameworks have convenient ways to handle sequential/parallel executions of test. You can parametrize test class to run the same tests on multiple browsers. There is an attribute in TestNG called [Parameters](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Parameters.html) which can be used with setting.xml for cross browser testing without duplicating the code. An example shown [here](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-multi-browser-cross-browser/)

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would no do that.

Most of the time it is pointless to *immediately* run your test against multiple browsers. Most of the problems you run into as you are developing new code or changing old code is not due to browser incompatibilities. Sure, these happens, but most of the time a test will fail because, well, your logic is wrong, and it will not just fail on one browser but on all of them. What do you gain from getting told X times rather than just once that your code is buggy? You've just wasted your time. I typically get the code working on Chrome and *then* run it against the other browsers.

(By the way, I run my tests against about 10 different combinations of OS, browser and browser version. 3 combinations is definitely not good enough for good coverage. IE 11 does not behave the same as IE 10, for instance. I know from experience.)

Moreover, the interleaving of tests from multiple browsers just seems generally confusing to me. I like one test report to cover only one configuration (OS, browser, browser version) so that I know if there are any problems exactly which configuration is problematic without having to untangle what failed on which browser.